# A question about 'reduced row echelon form' in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

please look at the image.
[image]

I can't understand the proof of Theorem 3.15 (a)

I will write down exactly the same proof in my text book.

It says

Proof. Since (A|B) is in reduced row echelon form, (A|B) must have m nonzero rows. Clearly these rows

are linearly independent by the definition of the reduced row echelon form, and so rank(A|B) = m.

Thus rank(A) = m.

I can't understand particularly the first part. that is "Since (A|B) is in reduced row echelon form,"

In my opinion,  even if (A|B) is not reduced row echelon form, since the system has m nonzero equations

and by the condition 'rank(A) = rank(A|B)' the system is consistent, (A|B) must have m nonzero rows.

so in the proof, I think the sentence " Since (A|B) is in reduced row echelon form" is redundant.

that condition is not necessary to argue that (A|B) must have m nonzero rows.

but why is it in the proof??